# Why do my test fail intermittently when running the whole suite?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

One of my tests is failing intermittently when running the whole suite, but it doesn't fail when running it by itself.

I created a very basic repository with a vanilla application that reproduces the issue:
https://github.com/juanazam/ember-cli-test-issue.

Basically, I created a component with a text field and a button. The button is disabled while the text is empty.

The issues happens when two tests use the fillIn helper on the input.

Here is the testing code taken from the vanilla app:

```
test('test 1', function(assert) {
  visit('/');

  fillIn('input[type=text]', "Algo");

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentRouteName(), "index");
  });
});

test('test 2', function(assert) {
  visit('/');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.ok(find('input[type=submit]').is(':disabled'));
  });

  fillIn('input[type=text]', "Algo");

  andThen(function() {
    assert.ok(!find('input[type=submit]').is(':disabled'));
  });
});
```

As you can see test 1 only fills the input but doesn't do anything with it. The second test tests if the button is disabled.

Test 2 fails intermittently when running the whole suite. If you run ember test -s it fails, if you reload the browser tab (re running the whole suite without restarting the server process) it passes. The same behavior happens with multiple runs (one run fails, the next succeeds).

I didn't create a twiddle reproduction case because the test runner doesn't behave the same way.

Comment: What ember version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

With you app:

`ember test` will always fail.

`ember test --filter 'test 1'` will always pass.

`ember test --filter 'test 2'` will always **pass**.

If you split your 2 test functions into different acceptance tests `ember test` will always pass.

Answer (score 0):

Qunit in the browser tries to execute failing tests first. (I think to reduce the time until the most interesting failing tests are executed.). With ember -s your tests are always executed in order and tests are failing (I guess test 2 failes because test1 already filled your input and it is not initially disabled as expected).

When reloading qunit in browser after the first failed test, the failing test2 is executed first (and passes).

Also have a look on https://dockyard.com/blog/2014/04/17/ember-object-self-troll . There might be a problem within your component definition leading to the unexpectedly filled input in test2.